# Eclipse job blocks access to workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a long running operation that is run as a Job.
Problem is, as long as the job runs at the background , I'm denied of access to my workspace. (a GMF diagram, if relevant). ( Under the progress view, I can see a pending Job saying "waiting user operation")

Is there any flag or priority that needs to be changed in order to make the job a non-blocking one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is the developer that decides whether the job is blocking or not. Usually based on whether the internal structures are in a sane state during the execution of the job, etc.

There are no way the stop a job in the general case. Even if you can cancel the job, it is still the developer of the job that decides if and when to check for the cancel state...

Comment: So where can I change the behavior of a job - making it a non - blocking job?

Comment: I assume that you are the developer of the job - :-) - you sub-class `Job` instead of using ProgressDialog or friends. Also make sure you use the `ISchedulingRule` correctly.

Comment: :) Are you saying that a job being a blocker depends on which objects it operates on? Thanks!